# Best way to output undetermined html (c#)

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm in the process of creating a survey system. This survey can have any number of questions of any html input type and the questions can have any number of options. Currently, I'm looping through this data and building the html using StringBuilder and then applying it to a div using innerHTML. Considering the complexity of the html, I found that StringBuilder would be the best option.

I'm researching other ways to output this data, one being Repeater, but a repeater or any other control doesn't seem fit for this task. I don't have a problem with using StringBuilder. It gets the job done. However, some people frown on using StringBuilder. I would like to hear other peoples input on this.

Comment: Who exactly is frowning on using the stringbuilder? I think they might be frowning on writing code in ASP.net to render the html, not the Stringbuilder class.

Comment: This sounds like a user-control-per-question-type type of situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably better of using some of the webcontrols, rather than generic html.

For example, you can create a table, and bind textbox, checkbox and listbox controls to this at runtime based on the questions. You can then loop through these and read the values on postback.

In my opinion, this will be a lot simpler than writing the complete html output and then writing a handler for the submissions.

Comment: I'm experimenting with this now. This sounds like the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself preferring to use StringBuilder, rather than an ASP.NET forms controls to build html I'd honestly suggest switching to using ASP.NET MVC rather than ASP.NET forms.  It supports creating views in a much more natural way for that sort of use.

Comment: I probably would, but that is not my decision.

Answer (score 1):

I'm firmly in the camp that agrees with @ChrisBint. Use custom controls...

**HOWEVER - There are situations - even within custom controls (which, for all we know, you're already using) - where you NEED to do stuff like this.**

In that case, I would recommend implementing a custom server control using **HtmlTextWriter** to generate the output - which is what MS uses inside their controls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx

> Writes markup characters and text to
>   an ASP.NET server control output
>   stream. This class provides formatting
>   capabilities that ASP.NET server
>   controls use when rendering markup to
>   clients.